# How to save to two tables using one SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, sql, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy ORM class, linked to MySQL, which works great at saving the data I need down to the underlying table. However, I would like to also save the identical data to a ***second*** archive table.

Here's some psudocode to try and explain what I mean

```
my_data = Data() #An ORM Class
my_data.name = "foo"

#This saves just to the 'data' table
session.add(my_data)

#This will save it to the identical 'backup_data' table
my_data_archive = my_data
my_data_archive.__tablename__ = 'backup_data'
session.add(my_data_archive)

#And commits them both
session.commit()
```

Just a heads up, I am not interested in mapping a class to a JOIN, as in: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/mappers.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining what this duplicate would buy you. What are you trying to accomplish? It is probably more in keeping with the operation of MySQL to have the DBM perform such redundancy on your behalf with the application layer remaining simple.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: 
The Data table will have processing and summarization on it at a later time, however we still want all the raw data for auditing purposes. Hence, unaltered data should be saved also in the data_backup table. (These are example names)

Comment: Also, I'm of the opinion that putting logic, like you suggest, in the DB harms my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I list some options below. I would go for the DB trigger if you do not need to work on those objects in your model.

- use database trigger to do this job for you
- create a [SessionExtension](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/interfaces.html?highlight=sessionextension#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.SessionExtension.before_flush) which will create and add to session copy-objects (usually on before_flush). **Edit-1:** You can take [versioning example](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/examples/versioning/history_meta.py) from SA as a basic; this code is doing even more then you need.
- see [SA Versioning example](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/examples.html#module-versioning) which will not only give you a copy of the object, but the whole version history, which might be what you wish for
- see [Reverse mapping from a table to a model in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850988/reverse-mapping-from-a-table-to-a-model-in-sqlalchemy/2859576#2859576) question, where the proposed solution is described in the [blogpost](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/?p=13).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but even after reading the resources you have given me, I am unsure how to proceed. Would you be able to give me a small example on how to, very simply, save a single model to two database tables? The simpler the better really.

Comment: A trigger is certainly simple, but it means putting logic in the DB right? I'm not sure that's the best way...

Comment: It depends. What is `logic`? Is this really part of your `business` requirement (which the model could reflect and implement) or is this a `non-functional` requirement? Most probably it is latter, and `triggers` will handle the job in much more simple and less error prone way. Example: are you sure that you will update your data only via the `model`? Because if not, then you will not be able to log the changes for audit reasons; but the triggers will. What I am trying to say is: you the right tool for the right purpose. You can do it in SA, but believe me - you need more exp. in SA to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 identical models: one mapped to main table and another mapped to archive table. Create a `MapperExtension` with redefined method `after_insert()` (depending on your demands you might also need `after_update()` and `after_delete()`). This method should copy data from main model to archive and add it to the session. There are some tricks to copy all columns and many-to-many relations automagically.

Note, that you'll have to `flush()` session twice to store both objects since unit of work is computed before mapper extension adds new object to the session. You can redefine `Session.flush()` to take care of this problem. Also auto-incremented fields are assigned when the object is flushed, so you'll have to delay copying if you need them too.

It is one possible scenario which is proved to work. I'd like to know if there is a better way.